# Django - Multiple annotations with Prefetch objects

Tags: sql, django, orm, annotations

I have a model `test` with two **m2m** fields: `foo` and `bar`.

I'm trying to annotate a conditional count of these related fields, i.e. to count the related objects that meet a certain condition. Retrieving this information outside of the queryset is not an option, because I need to use the annotated fields to order the result.

I've tried the following:

**1. Using Prefetch objects**

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch, Count

prefetch_foo = Prefetch('foo_set', queryset=foo.objects.filter(<some condition>))
prefetch_bar = Prefetch('bar_set', queryset=bar.objects.filter(<some condition>))
result = test.objects.prefetch_related(prefetch_foo, prefetch_bar).annotate(n_foo=Count('foo'), n_bar=Count('bar'))
```

This doesn't work, because `prefetch_related` gets applied after `annotate`.

**2. Using conditional expressions**

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Case, When
from django.db.models.fields import IntegerField

foo_sum = Sum(Case(When(foo__<some condition>, then=1), default=0,
                        output_field=IntegerField())))
bar_sum = Sum(Case(When(bar__<some condition>, then=1), default=0,
                        output_field=IntegerField())))
result = test.objects.annotate(n_foo=foo_sum, n_bar=bar_sum)
```

This doesn't work because of this bug on multiple `Sum` annotations: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060

**3. Using RawSQL**

```
sql = "SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN foo.<condition> "
      "THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM app_test "
      "LEFT OUTER JOIN app_foo "
      "ON (app_test.id = foo.test_id) "
      "GROUP BY test.id"
result = test.objects.annotate(n_foo=RawSQL(sql, []))
# Same method for bar
```

I'm stuck here, because this retrieves the `SUM` for all rows and I can't find a way to add something like `"WHERE test.id = <ID of the object the annotation corresponds to>"`.

Is there any way to get the right single row from the custom SQL? Or another workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The `Count` function in Django now has a `filter` parameter that should be what you are looking for.

[See documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation).

In this case:

```
result = test.objects.annotate(n_foo=Count('foo_set', filter=Q(<some condition>)), n_bar=Count('bar_set', filter=Q(<some condition)))
```

should give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do that with Django ORM (because of that 8 years old bug) but using `HAVING` on the RawSQL should work. Have you tried something like this?

```
sql = """SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN app_foo.<condition> 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM app_test 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN app_foo 
      ON (app_test.id = app_foo.test_id) 
      GROUP BY app_test.id 
      HAVING app_test.id = <ID of the object the annotation corresponds to>"""
```

T

Comment: `django.db.models.F` is not available inside `RawSQL`, so I'm unable to include the object's attributes in the SQL string.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a change to your SQL. You don't use FROM to get the app_test. Have you seen SQL subqueries before?

```
sql = """
  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN app_foo.<condition> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
  FROM app_foo 
  WHERE app_test.id = app_foo.id  # app_test comes from outside the sub query.

  """
result = test.objects.annotate(n_foo=RawSQL(sql, []))
```

The actual query that gets run will be similar to...

```
SELECT app_test.*, (
  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN app_foo.<condition> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
  FROM app_foo 
  WHERE app_test.id = app_foo.id  ) AS n_foo
FROM app_test
```